# Creation of mobile keypad for touchscreen using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a number keypad using javascript. On each button click i have done the below:-
Buttons are:-

```
<input type="button" value="2" class="num-key" onclick="insertvalue(this.value)">
<input type="button" value="3" class="num-key" onclick="insertvalue(this.value)">
<input type="button" value="4" class="num-key" onclick="insertvalue(this.value)">
```

the method is:-

```
function insertvalue(value)
{   
document.getElementById('number').value=document.getElementById('number').value + value;
}
```

It is working but it is to slow. If i will do this using jquery it might be fast. But i have done this using jquery

```
$( ".num-key" ).click(function() {
$(".num-text").val($(this).val());
});
```

But it is not working please tell me how to do this.

Comment: your code appears to be fine, could please check whether there is any error logged in the console of the browser. Is the element referenced by $(".num-text") a textbox?

Comment: yeah num-text is the text box

Comment: what do you mean by "it is not working" - Is it the numbers not getting appended or numbers not displayed in the textbox at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$( ".num-key" ).on('click',function() {
      $(".num-text").val(($('.num-text').val()) + (this.value));
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/Aj95A/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to

```
$(".num-key").click(function() {
    var inc = $(".num-text").val();      
    $(".num-text").val($(this).val() + inc);
});
```

Comment: mum-key is the number key and num-text is my textbox. What do you mean by #number

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use it as a keyboard, you should keep the previous value of your text input:

```
$(".num-key").click(function() {
    $(".num-text").val($(".num-text").val() + $(this).val());
});
```

here's the link:
[Demo](http://jsbin.com/EjitEz/1/)

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way is to use: ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YbhdJ/))

```
$(".num-key").click(function () {
    var currentValue = $(".num-text").val();
    $(".num-text").val(currentValue + $(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this full keypad demo: http://jsfiddle.net/devmgs/XGuVZ/

```
$( ".num-key" ).click(function() {
    if($(this).val()=="D")
         $(".num-text").val($(".num-text").val().substring(0, $(".num-text").val().length - 1)); 
    else if($(this).val()=="C")
         $(".num-text").val("");
    else
          $(".num-text").val($(".num-text").val()+$(this).val());
});
```

Comment: No need for the caps.